# Events is not capturing in google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, shopify, google-analytics-firebase

i am going to capture the outgoing link in Shopify . for that i have found some solutions in online

here is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var localserver = “mysite.com”;
     $(“a”).not(“a[href^=’http://”+localserver+”‘]”).not(“a[href^=’https://”+localserver+”‘]”).click(function(){
        $(this).attr(“target”, “blank”);
          ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘links’, ‘click’, $(this).attr(‘href’));
            });
             });
        </script>
```

(ref link  [reference link](http://ecommppc.com/2014/08/28/track-outbound-link-clicks-on-your-shopify-site/) )

this code i have pasted in my account . but still i am not getting any events in google analytic.

why its not working ? i need to create any events in google analytic ?

Comment: You are using strange quotes, make sure that this is no problem.

Comment: You might consider using the autotrack plugin for Google Analytics (which automatically adds outbound link tracking). The project is here: https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack

Comment: This has been answered somewhere before, but @kabaehr is onto something. Make sure you use straight quotes rather than the dreaded smart quotes.

Comment: i made that quotes correction . but still i am unable to track the externals links .